# How to finish A activity from B activity in Android

Tags: android

Hi i am making demo application in which there are three activities. A, B, C. I am on `B` Activity and on button click starting C Activity. On same time I want to finish A activity.

I found some flag ClEAR_TOP and CLEAR_TASK but it is not for same which i am looking.

Is there any way to do in android ?

Any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this on your button click : `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

It does clear your previous activities and start a new one.

UPDATE

If you want to support older android version, use `IntentCompat` instead of `Intent`.

Comment: Thanks. You may want to consider upvoting the other answers (like i did) because they will work too, but i think this is the most correct way to do it.

Comment: guys awesome thing of this answer is `IntentCompat`. i never heard of this.

Comment: Yes, i need to do some research it when i faced your problem. Its because my project need to support old android version. Fortunately, Android has this class :D

Answer (score 1):

The right way of doing it is start activity B using startActivityForResult. When you click the button in activity B it will set a result intercepted by activity A. At that point activity A will call finish() on itself and start activity C.

Answer (score 0):

A) In your activity A have a static function as follows:

```
public static void killMe()
{
finish();
}
```

From the button click of Activity B, call this function as follows:

```
A.killMe();
```

B) You can even do this by using startActivityForResult() to start activity B from activity A. Then depending on the return value from your activity B, you can then immediately finish() the predecessor activity A to simulate the behavior you want.